# Destroying spatial index using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, spatial-index

QGIS 1.9

Is it possible to destroy a spatial index?  I am noticing that if I generate a spatial index on a set of polylines (within a plugin), split one of the lines, and then recreate the spatial index, the index values within the spatial index are doubled.

For example:

I have 5 lines, so the spatial index has feature 0 - 4.  I split one of the lines and recreate the spatial index.  The spatial index should have indices 0-5, but it has indices 0-9.

Deleting the features from the spatial index does not help with the indexing issue.

### Code

```
class slicer:

    def init(self):
        '''standard stuff here'''
    def activated(self):
        '''standard stuff here'''
        create_temp_polylines()

    def create_temp_polylines(self):
        self.line_layer = QgsVectorLayer('Make the layer')
        self.spat_index = QgsSpatialIndex()
        self.point_layer = point_layer #Grabbed by iterating over layer list
        pt_prov = self.point_layer.dataProvider()
        polylines = {}
        for feat in self.point_layer.dataProvider():
            '''build the line geometries based on a membership attribute'''
        for key, value in polyline.iteritems():
            temp_polyline = QgsFeature()
            temp_polyline.setGeometry(value)
            temp_polyline.setAttributes([attr1, attr2, ...])
            line_layer.startEditing()
            line_layer.addFeature(temp_polyline, True)
            self.spat_index.insertFeature(temp_polyline)
        line_layer.commitChanges()

    def split(self, cut_line):
        '''logic to split a polyline'''
        '''logic to update the attribute table'''
        '''commit the changes to the DB'''
        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayer(self.line_layer.id())
        self.create_temp_polylines()
```

### Spatial_Reference Checking Code

```
'''draw a line on screen (rubberband)'''

def get_intersect(self, rubberband):
    line = rubberband.asGeometry().asPolyline()
    intersections = self.spat_index.intersects(rubberband.asGeometry.boundingBox())
    touches = set()
    for id in intersections:
    id = (id * -1) -1 #Why are they ids negative longs?
    '''convert if to feature object'''
    '''check touches'''
    if touching:
        touches.add(feature.id())
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the *.qix file and rebuilding the index?

Comment: This is within a plugin, on an in-memory layer,  so the spatial index should only be created in memory.

Comment: I'm guessing you are using a QgsSpatialIndex?

Comment: Yes.  In init() I loop through an input point layer to generate a polyline layer.  The spatial index is off the poyline layer.  Then split, update the point layer attribution, recreate the polyline layer.  It is on the recreate that the spatial index is duplicated.  I tried both reinstantiating QgsSpatialIndex and emptying it out with deleteFeature.  No joy on either.  I see that the API has a ~QgsSpatialIndex (destructor), but I don't think it is accessible via python.

Comment: Can you post your code.  Just the important parts

Comment: Code / Pseudocode added.  I can flesh in some more if needed, but these are the important parts.

Comment: `self.spat_index = QgsSpatialIndex()` will recreate the spatial index.  Something else might be going on here.

Comment: Exactly my thought.  I thought that perhaps it was because the variable was not going out of scope, but that does not appear to be the issue.  As you said, calling soat_index again should force it to reinitialize.

Comment: How are you testing what the index has in it?

Comment: Updated with additional code.  Added a comment wondering why intersections are indexed by negative long.

Comment: Negative ids are for uncommited features.